# Why do miniKanren names always end with `o`?

Tags: clojure, scheme, logic, minikanren

All miniKanren relations end with the letter `o`.  What is the motivation for this?
I see that the Clojure core.logic library also does this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the Preface of *The Reasoned Schemer*, they explain it thus:

> A relation, a function that returns a goal as its value, ends its name with a superscript '*o*' (e.g., *car<sup>o</sup>* and *null<sup>o</sup>*).

So, it's a notation to denote a relation.

Answer (score 5):

It's because the authors of *The Reasoned Schemer* wanted the notation of miniKanren relations to be evocative of ordinary Scheme predicates which end in `?` (e.g., `null?`, `pair?`) by convention. The superscript <sup>o</sup>, if you squint enough (and have heard this story before), looks like a modified `?`.